# Rails 3 - has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, model-associations

I have 2 models - **Teacher** and **Subject**. A want to connect them via Join table with name **Qualification**.

It looks like i do something wrong:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects, :join_table => "Qualification"
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers, :join_table => "Qualification"
end
```

My migration:

```
class CreateQualificationJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :qualification, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :subject_id
      t.integer :teacher_id
    end
    add_index :qualification, :subject_id
    add_index :qualification, :teacher_id
  end
end
```

When i open rails console and print, for example

```
ruby-1.9.3-head :013 > Qualification
```

I get this:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Qualification
    from (irb):13
    from /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Believe you need a model called Qualification that maps to the table.

Comment: @NekoNova: only if he ExiRe wants to do something with the join table itself, else, let AR do the dirty work. See my answer below for an attached link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, creating the table in a migration doesn't define your model. You have to create a `Qualification` model in `app/models/qualification.rb`:

```
class Qualification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subjects
  belongs_to :teachers
end
```

Second, if you're using Rails 3, throw out `has_and_belongs_to_many` and use `has_many :through`:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :qualifications
  has_many :subjects, :through => :qualifications
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :qualifications
  has_many :teachers, :through => :qualifications
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only use `has_and_belongs_to_many` if you don't intend to work directly with the join table. In your case, use it if you don't intend to use Qualification itself but only Teacher and Subject and let Active Record do the dirty work. If you have anything to do with the join model, use has_many :through.

Read more here: [Choosing Between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many)

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3 the best way is make intermediate table qualification through migration

the attributes will be like of this table

subject_id:integer
   teacher_id:integer

and also make class of qualification like this

```
class Qualification < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subjects
  has_many :teachers
end
```

and then define other two models like

```
 class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :qualifications
   has_many :subjects, :through => :qualifications
 end

 class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :qualifications
  has_many :teachers, :through => :qualifications
 end
```

and read this link carefully also

```
   http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/1/15/basic-rails-association-cardinality
```

Comment: I believe that you should have `belongs_to` instead of `has_many` in `Qualification` model.