# How do I query belongs_to through a HABTM in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to understand the best way to query a pretty basic HABTM relationship. I want to  find all races by the associated discipline.id. Since I have a HABTM relationship in the middle I am just getting confused on the best way to do this.

```
class Discipline < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_types
end

class EventType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :discipline
  has_and_belongs_to_many :races
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :event_types
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this RailsCast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944542/rails-3-has-and-belongs-to-many) and this quiz (http://www.codequizzes.com/learn-rails/many-to-many-relationships).  Then post your schema, the code you tried in rails console, and the error message you got.  BTW, welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a query on races with event_types joined and using a where to include only entries where the discipline_id is correct.

```
Race.joins(:event_types).where('event_types.discipline_id = ?', discipline.id)
```

This assumes you have the discipline loaded in a variable `discipline`... if alternatively you have the discipline in an instance variable `@discipline` then change the end of the query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible to define it this way:

```
class Discipline < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_types
  has_many :races, through: :event_types
```

Then just call `discipline.races`.

If not, I think, this should work:

```
discipline.event_types.includes(:races).map { |e| e.races }.flatten
```

`map` returns a new Array with the result of the block for each result, thus the races for each event. `flatten` makes a out of the nested array (the array of races per event type) a flat one (just the races). Maybe you also want to call `uniq` on that. And `includes` eager loads all races at once instead of one per event type.